# How to disable/enable a PHP module with phpdismod?

Tags: php, nginx, php-extension, server-administration

I want to be able to turn on/off Xdebug a simple and fast way. To disable it I tried out `phpdismod`, but only results in a warning:

```
$ phpdismod xdebug
WARNING: Module xdebug ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.0/mods-available
WARNING: Module xdebug ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.0/mods-available
```

**How to get a PHP module disabled/enabled with `phpdismod`?**

---

Environment: Ubuntu 14.04, nginx 1.4.6, PHP 7.0 FPM.

```
$ ls -l /etc/php/mods-available/ | grep "xdebug"
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 743 Jul  1 16:16 xdebug.ini
$ ls -l /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/ | grep "xdebug"
$ ls -l /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/ | grep "xdebug"
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Feb 17 23:08 20-xdebug.ini -> /etc/php/mods-available/xdebug.ini
$ ls -l /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/ | grep "xdebug"
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Feb 17 23:08 20-xdebug.ini -> /etc/php/mods-available/xdebug.ini
$ ls -l /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/ | grep "xdebug"
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Feb 17 23:16 20-xdebug.ini -> /etc/php/mods-available/xdebug.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem with the docker-lemp-stack.

In the php70/Dockerfile, the PHP module configs line puts the local xdebug.ini file into /etc/php/mods-available/xdebug.ini (which you see in your setup).

I've amended the line from ...

`ADD conf/mods-available/xdebug.ini /etc/php/mods-available/xdebug.ini`

to ...

`ADD conf/mods-available/xdebug.ini /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xdebug.ini`

and rebuilt the docker image

I now get the right handling for the env var which controls the xdebug.

So if you move the files to the right location you should be OK.